# hide nav when click mobile view (scroll one page)

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How could I hide the nav bar when I click the link? here is my code below. I am trying some of the codes provided here in stackoverflow but it didn't works. can you help me with my problem.

```html
 <!-- Navigation -->
<div id="nav">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse"> <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> </button>
         <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">
         <div class="hover13">
    <figure><img src="img/Julius-Logo-header4.png" alt="" class="img-responsive"></figure>
   </div>
   </a>
        
      
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
          <li class="hidden"> <a href="#page-top"></a> </li>
          <li> <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a> </li>
          
          <li> <a class="page-scroll hidden-xs hidden-sm" href="#offer">What we offer</a> </li>
            <li> <a class="page-scroll hidden-lg hidden-md" href="#offer1">What we offer</a> </li>
          <li> <a class="page-scroll" href="#photos">Project</a> </li>
          
          <li> <a class="page-scroll  hidden-xs hidden-sm" href="#blogs">Blogs</a> </li>
            <li> <a class="page-scroll hidden-lg hidden-md" href="#blogs1">Blogs</a> </li>
          
          <li> <a class="page-scroll" href="#event">Events</a> </li>
          <li> <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".navbar-toggle").click(function() {
    $(".navbar-main-collapse").toggleClass('hiddenNav');
  });
});
```

With this class in your CSS:

```
.hiddenNav {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the response @GrowingBrick. I tried your given code but the problem was all of the nav link are hided.

Comment: Yes, is it not what you have asked? If you wanted to hide the whole nav bar change `.navbar-main-collapse` selector to `#nav` but then also the toggle button would be hidden because it is inside the same container

Answer (score 0):

I have read you question, you want to hide the navbar when link is clicked. This is very simple in Jquery. Use .hide() built-in function in jquery. code below

```
$("#hidenavbarlink").click(function(){
     $("#nav").hide();
});
```

**I hope this will help you**

Comment: thank you for the response @Sheraz, I tried you given code, but its still the same. can't close/ hide the nav when I clicked.